# How to complete hamburger animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, hamburger-menu

Sorry I am a beginner.
How can I complete this function. By click on the burger, the buns rotate and form a 'x'. After clicking the 'x' it should go backwards again. My second issue is that when the buns have formed the 'x', they still make the hover-move (moving vertically).

```
$('#hamburger').click(function() {
  $('nav').fadeToggle(200);
});

$('#hamburger').click(function() {
  $('#top-bun').css('transform','rotate(45deg)');
  $('#bottom-bun').css('transform','rotate(-45deg)');
  $('#top-bun').css('top','35%');
  $('#bottom-bun').css('bottom','35%');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bncqjxa9/

Comment: Don’t be sorry for beginning something 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('#hamburger').click(function() {
    $('nav').fadeToggle(200);
});
        
$('#hamburger').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
#hamburger{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 150;
 top: 30px;
 right: 30px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 25px;
 border: 0;
 background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#hamburger .bun{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100%;
 background: black;
 transition: 0.2s;
}
#top-bun{
 top: 0;
 margin-top: 3px;
}
#bottom-bun{
 bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
}
#hamburger.open #top-bun {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 35%;
}
#hamburger.open #bottom-bun {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    bottom: 35%;
}
nav{
 display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hamburger">
  <div class="bun" id="top-bun"></div>
  <div class="bun" id="bottom-bun"></div>
</button>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

It can help to reduce techniques for animation. In this case you played with CSS and JavaScript. To make it easier, I reduced it to just CSS and just toggled one class to have the control over the animation in one place (in the css file).

Further improvements could be to not use the id selector for styling (it is very limited, because it is absolute). Try to not nest selectors to deep, otherwise it can decrease performance or you loose control over styling at some point. Take a look at systematic or modular approaches like BEM for example. If you are strict with organising your styles, you won’t get into hassle later one.

Another thing is, if you animate you elements by changing CSS attributes and already go with `transform` then why not stick with it? You can avoid using other attributes like `top` for example. Can improve performance, too. ([High Performance Animation](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)).
And concerning your JavaScript, you can save selected elements in variables, to not having to select them again.
`var $hamburger = $('#hamburger'); $hamburger.on('click', ...);`
Also you can use the `on` method, which is kind of preferred when it comes to event handling in jQuery.
`$hamburger.on('click', function() {});` instead of `$hamburger.click(function() {});`

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks so nice and smooth **